# Prepared statement returns no result with like-query

Tags: java, jdbc, db2, prepared-statement, sql-like

I'm trying to make a search with PreparedStatement, but the query returns no result:

```
 final Session session = em.unwrap(Session.class);

 final String sql = "SELECT u.name FROM Users AS u WHERE u.name LIKE ?";

 session.doWork(new Work() {
            @Override
            public void execute(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
                try (PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql))    
 {
      stmt.setString(1, "%" + nameTerm + "%");
      stmt.executeQuery();
            } 
 }
 });
```

There are records in the DB, it should return a result. I test my query in iSeries Navigator and it works. But if I executed it through PreparedStatement it returns no result. I'm using DB2 database.

**EDIT**

I forgot to mention that this problem happens only if the search term contains apostrophe.

Comment: You aren't executing anything in the above code, you are only setting a parameter value.

Comment: And don't use `executeUpdate()` for queries despite what others are suggesting -- use `execute()` or `executeQuery()`

Answer (score 0):

`pstmt.executeUpdate()` executes prepared statement but I don't find it in your code.
you have to call `executeUpdate()` api to execute your prepared statement.

Try

```
 try (PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql)){
      stmt.setString(1, "%" + nameTerm + "%");
      stmt.executeUpdate();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are only setting the `PreparedStatement`, you are not actually calling the `executeUpdate()` method, which makes the call out to the database. Check out this [PreparedStatement Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)